# Change a value of find -printf in bash

Tags: bash, awk, find, printf

I'm using find to print a line for each file and directory:

```
find ${rootdirectory} -printf '%p,%T@\n' >> ${outputfile}
```

However, I like to convert `%T@` from unixepoch to Windows FILETIME:

```
filetime=$(( (%T@ + 11644473600) * 10000000 ))
find ${rootdirectory} -printf '%p,${filetime}\n' >> ${outputfile}
```

This doesn't work of course because `%T@` is not set prior to `find -printf`.

What is the **fastest** way to find millions of files while changing a found integer? I already have a solution with `stat` but it's extremely slow:

```
find ${rootdirectory} -exec 1>${outputfile} sh -c 'for file in "${1}"/* ;
  do
    unixtime=$(stat -c%Y ${file})
    filetime=$(( (${unixtime} + 11644473600) * 10000000 ))
    stat -c%n,${filetime} ${file}
  done' none {}  \;
```

I changed this to a variation with `-printf` but `T` is not recognized:

```
find ${rootdirectory} -exec 1>${outputfile} sh -c 'for file in "${1}"/* ;
  do
    unixtime=$(printf %T@)
    filetime=$(( (${unixtime} + 11644473600) * 10000000 ))
    -printf %p,${filetime}
  done' none {}  \;
```

My last hope was this:

```
print_format="%p,$(( %T@ + 11644473600 ))\n"
find ${rootdirectory} -printf "$print_format"
```

For the sake of completeness, this doesn't work:

```
find ${rootdirectory} -printf '%p,$(( (%T@ + 11644473600) * 10000000 ))\n'
```

Does anybody have any ideas? And would `xargs` be faster than `exec`?

Comment: And what is the point of doing this conversion?

Comment: Converting unixtime to FILETIME makes the time readable for Windows applications :)

Comment: I just added awk to the tags

Comment: It might be a lot faster if you use `exec ... \+` instead of `exec ... \;`.  (That is, if your find supports `+`, it will be faster, so perhaps I should say your find might support `+`)

Comment: But why are you doing `for file in $1` and iterating over a single argument?  You'll want to iterate over all the arguments.

Comment: @WilliamPursell IIRC `+` gets all lines at once, while `;` iterates over each line. Since each file has its own filetime, that's what I picked.

Comment: Using `;` spawns a separate shell for each name.  Using `+` will pass many paths to one shell, which can then iterate over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'killer' in your solution (given large number of files) are the repeated execution (one per file) of the 'shell'. As you have already pointed out 'find' does not support arithmetic on operator.

One alternative is to use a post-processor (awk, Perl, Python) that will read the output from find, and perform the conversion.

```
# Using printf
find ${rootdirectory} -printf '%p,%T@\n' | awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, '{ printf ("%s,%d\n",  $1, ($2+ 11644473600) * 10000000)}'

# On 32 bit environment, using %.0f
find ${rootdirectory} -printf '%p,%T@\n' | awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, '{ printf ("%s,%.0f\n",  $1, ($2+ 11644473600) * 10000000)}'

# Or using regular print
find ${rootdirectory} -printf '%p,%T@\n' | awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, '{ printf ("%s,%d\n",  $1, ($2+ 11644473600) * 10000000)}'
```

Given only one invocation of `awk`, this will be much faster than attempted solutions.

Using xargs can speedup the code, but only if you use some 'bulking', where large number of files will be processed by a single command. It is unlikely to be faster than 'awk' - single process.

Using `bash` only solution will be hard, since bash does not support math on floating point values (On Mint 19, @T includes fraction).

Comment: Thanks! Although this gives me a scientific notation. I have to use `printf` instead but it's giving me a hard time adding a `\n`. Where do you put it?

Comment: @kamikater code modified to use printf with no decimals

Comment: Now the result is always `2147483647`. A given time of `1572178968,8001529300` should become `132166525688001529,3` but as an integer `132166525688001529`. No rounding necessary. This is an `awk` question and I all now is little `sed`.

Comment: The 2147483647 seems to be 32/64  bit issue. On my machine (64 bit), I'm getting 132165795920421120 or similar. Using '%.0f' may solve the problem on 32 bit. See 2nd line in the code above

Comment: That's it! Thank you @dash-o :) I now very little `awk`. If you could just tell why this isn't working, it would be very appreciated: `find ${rootdirectory} -printf '"%p",%s,%T@\n' | awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, '{ printf ("%s,%s,%.0f\n",  $1, $2, ($3+ 11644473600) * 10000000 )}' >> ${outputfile}`

Comment: @kamikater can you clarify 'not working' ? it produces output on Mint Linux 19

Comment: I don't know why my answer disappeared as it now looks like I ignored you. I wrote: "Nevermind, it was my fault. Thank you very much"